# Morris.js bar chart - remove excess space where labels would be

Tags: jquery, morris.js

I want to display a very simple bar chart with no labels - I've managed to achieve this but there seems to be a lot of padding around the entire chart. I've set my chart to have a 90px height but the bars are only 40px and there seems to be about 25px padding around the entire chart.

Ideally I'd like to remove this padding - is this extra space from the labels that I removed?

Here is an image of my chart:

[image]

Here is my jQuery:

```
function barChart() {
    window.m = Morris.Bar({
      // ID of the element in which to draw the chart.
      element: 'myfirstchart',
      axes: false,
      grid: false,
      hideHover: 'always',
      barColors: ['#00CDC6'],
      gridTextSize: 0,
      // Chart data records -- each entry in this array corresponds to a point on
      // the chart.
      data: [
    { visits: '01 June', value: 0 },
    { visits: '02 June', value: 1 },
    { visits: '03 June', value: 2 },
    { visits: '04 June', value: 3 },
    { visits: '05 June', value: 4 }
    //More data would be here               
      ],
      // The name of the data record attribute that contains x-values.
      xkey: 'visits',
      // A list of names of data record attributes that contain y-values.
      ykeys: ['value'],
      // Labels for the ykeys -- will be displayed when you hover over the
      // chart.
      labels: ['Value']
    });
}
```

Is there a way to have an X start position of 0?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old, but the answer is to simply set the padding to a smaller size...

```js
padding: 1,
```

By default the padding is 25px by the look of it...